# how to receive a notification when someone sends me a message on visual studio live share?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I lately began using the **vscode** live share (**vscode** collaboration) extension me and my buddies
and the only difficulty that we have encountered using it is when one of my buddies reach out using that extension **chat feature** we don't receive any notification to let us know about him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that this feature is not yet implemented

here is the open issue on the extension project over Github

[Provide better visibility of new chat messages](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3974)